# Vertically align text in an html bootstrap row

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a bootstrap row with three columns inside (col-sm-2 ; col-sm-8; col-sm-2).
In the first column in will insert a card, in the second I will insert text and in the last column I will add a tool tip. I will repeat this row a lot of times.

Because I am new to html (and css) I am trying to vertically align the third column. In the image below I am showing and example of what I need highlighted in orange[image]. This is probably a very easy thing to do. Can anyone help? (the code below):

```
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <div id="panelImage">
          <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h4>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
        <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo 
                inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. 
                Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni 
                dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, 
                consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat 
                voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea 
                commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem 
                eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <p id="thing">Lorem ipsum</p>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

And below the css:

```
#panelImage{
  background-color: #dcdcdc;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-left: 3px;
  border-radius: 1px;
  border-color: coral;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 15px;
}

#panelText{
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#thing{
  top: 50%;
  justify-content: center;
  }
```

Comment: Post your CSS as well please. The HTML alone doesn't seem to exhibit the problem you described https://www.bootply.com/t1fujvBOle

Answer (score 0):

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
    <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia
      voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi
      tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui
      in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <p id="thing">Lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

you need something like this?

Comment: Yes! Thanks Ingrid! The first column was missing in your example, but this is waht I need!